# Flutter bottom sheet changing background heigth

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using bottom sheet in my app but its changing the background screen height. I need my background page fixed. And need to increase bottom sheet height

Here is my bottom sheet code

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class addQuestion extends StatefulWidget {



  @override
  _addQuestionState createState() => _addQuestionState();
}

class _addQuestionState extends State<addQuestion> {


  void _submitData(){

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double stackHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff404040),

          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: Radius.circular(15.0))
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Card(

          elevation: 5,
          color: Color(0xff404040),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right:10,
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10 ,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  maxLength: 56,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    counterText: '',
                      labelText: 'Would Question',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue
                      ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                ),
                TextField(
                  maxLength: 56,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    counterText: '',
                      labelText: 'Rather Question',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red
                      ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                ),

                RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                  _submitData();

                }, child: Text('Add Question', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white
                ),),color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]
As you see when keyboard open the background page is moving on the upside. And in rounded orders of bottom sheet, it's showing white corner don't know why its showing the need to transparent or remove this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of [bottom sheets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) in material design:

**Persistent**. A persistent bottom sheet shows information that supplements the primary content of the app. A persistent bottom sheet remains visible even when the user interacts with other parts of the app. Persistent bottom sheets can be created and displayed with the *ScaffoldState.showBottomSheet* function or by specifying the *Scaffold.bottomSheet* constructor parameter.

**Modal**. A modal bottom sheet is an alternative to a menu or a dialog and prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the app. Modal bottom sheets can be created and displayed with the *showModalBottomSheet* function.

**showBottomSheet method**

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: const Text('showBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>(
            (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('BottomSheet'),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: showbottom]

**showModalBottomSheet function **

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: showModal]

> The BottomSheet widget itself is rarely used directly. Instead, prefer to create a persistent bottom sheet with ScaffoldState.showBottomSheet or Scaffold.bottomSheet, and a modal bottom sheet with showModalBottomSheet.